# Wordpress Navigation Child/Parent

Tags: html, css, navigation, themes, dropdown

I've been customizing a Wordpress Theme (iconic-one) for an aquintance of mine. Everything is going according to plan, but I've ran into a problem.
I've modified the style of the navigation bar slightly, but one of the elements is not adjusting accordingly.
The problem is that when hovering over a child element of a dropdown, the parent element in the navigation bar goes back to the original color, which is blue.

Uploading the relevant code is an issue, as I have no idea what is causing the problem.

For reference: oefentherapievanuitdekern.nl is de website, you can see the problem occur on the main page.

Is there anyone who can point me in the right direction for a solution? Any help is greatly apreciated.

Kind regards,

Bik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I can see, there are two diffrent Stylesheets overwriting each other, i am not that deep into Wordpress, but maybe in ur Theme u can define `hover color` and `aktive color`
**AND** maybe `hover color` for sub-menu?

otherwise u have to work with code :P

Comment: Thats the general idea. Iconic-one creators are kind enough to supply you with an embedded custom.css to create your cusomt CSS without a child theme. The problem appears to be in the fact that I can't find the correct tag for the element that I wish to modify/style.

Comment: if yes: `a:hover{UR STYLE}` is making atm ur hover u want to have, but if u want to overwrite the other, u need to wirte sth like `.themonic-nav li a:hover{UR STYLE}`

Comment: I messed up some of the custom CSS, fixed it now and it works fine. Ty for the input!

Comment: I am glad it helped u :)